# Сессия Временные таблицы

Tags: sql

> В отличие от локальной глобальная временная таблица доступна всем
>   открытым сессиям базы данных.

Объясните, пожалуйста, как правильно понимать термин сессия

Comment: Вы бы указали ТОЧНО, о какой СУБД речь. Ибо в разных СУБД сии вещи могут быть реализованы по-разному...

Comment: *как правильно понимать термин сессия* В подавляющем большинстве случаев: со стороны клиентского приложения сессия - это установленное к БД подключение (connection). Т.е. приложение, установившее 2 соединения, использует 2 сессии (с точки зрения сервера это два разных независимых клиента). И через них можно работать с одной и той же глобальной таблицей, а вот локальная будет у каждого своя, и до чужой - не добраться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сессия- это сеанс.
Простыми словами, те кто работает с БД имеют в ней сессию. Когда пользователь отключается от БД его сессия завершается.

Comment: По сессией чаще понимается транзакция.

Comment: транзакция не обязательно связана с подключением к базе может выполняться локально?

Comment: @Cyber, в одном соединении может быть выполнено несколько транзакций. У MS SQL поочередно, у Firebird даже одновременно. Таким образом транзакция связана с соединением, но не один-к-одному, а многие-к-одному.